# How to specify multiple processors in PBS?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pbs

There are two options in the PBS queuing system (that I know of) that are related to multiple processes. This is the relevant line in the script  :

```
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
```

I always used just one process, and this went fine. However, to speed up things, I rewrote my script to use multiple processes. This works fine with testcases on a normal Desktop (without PBS), and now I want to use the big computer (with PBS). How do I make sure I use the right PBS settings? Do I need to change *nodes*, or *ppn*? I do not want to try something random, because I do not want to mess up other people's running jobs.

I use this function inside my Python script to create more processes:

```
multiprocessing.Process(name = name, target=multiprocess_function, args=args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PBS script, `nodes` stands for the number of *physical* nodes you want to allocate for your job, and `ppn` stands for the numper of *processors per node*, that is the number of CPU cores you want to allocate on each node. AFAIK, python `multiprocessing` module spawns several processes on the node you run it on, and if you want every subprocess run on its own core, you need to increase `ppn`.

Comment: No errors when I submitted this to PBS. I will accept this answer when the script starts running (and no system administrators send me angry e-mails)